# Manga about futuristic bunch of samurai and big warship

Tags: story-identification, manga

There is one manga I used to read when I was a kid (I'm 20 years old now), but I forgot the title.  I also forgot about the storyline.  What I remember is that the characters in the manga are a bunch of samurai who are a bit more futuristic. They each hold 3 weapons, a katana, an old rifle, and a spear.

They are at war by driving a big warship that is also futuristic.  And I'm sure it's not Yamato.

I think that's all I can remember, and it's an old manga.  I hope someone can help me because I'm curious half to death.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.